# Web services for downloading multiple images in spring MVC

Tags: android, spring-mvc, tomcat

I want to download multiple images from the tomcat server using spring mvc on my android application. Help me regarding this problem with both android and spring mvc code.

Answer (score 0):

Downloading all the images in a single request may consume lots of time.

**ANDROID** :What you can do is after getting images URLs from server you can use glide library by adding  `com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0` to android gradle configuration file.

And then pass all urls to this library.

It will be running in background so everything will go smoothly.

**SPRING-MVC** :

Write a method in controller which will read images from tomcat location and return the image as byte array something like below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getImage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getImage(@RequestParam (value="id" ,required = true)String id) {

        try{ 
            String rootPath = System.getProperty("catalina.home");
            String profilePicDirectory = rootPath + File.separator + "images" + File.separator  + id +".jpg";


            RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(profilePicDirectory, "r");
            byte[] b = new byte[(int)f.length()];
            f.readFully(b);
            f.close();
            final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG);
            return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(b, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(null, headers, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }
```